# Vite: how to specify the folders need to be watched

Tags: nuxt.js, rollupjs, vite

I am using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) in my SSR Nuxt project by [nuxt-vite](https://vite.nuxtjs.org/)

But the folder structure of my Nuxt project is not a default one but a custom one like this:

[image]

the Nuxt project is inside of a Laravel project (I referenced this [project](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-nuxt))

Once I run `npm run dev` with `vite: {ssr: true}`, because the `package.json` is located at the root dir but the Nuxt project is not, `Vite` will watch all the changes in the folders under root dir.

---

I try to specify the folders that Vite need to watch

accroding to the [vite-document](https://vitejs.dev/config/#build-watch) and [rollupjs document](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#watchinclude)

my `nuxt.config.js` is

```js
vite: {
  ssr: true,
  build: {
    watch: {
      include: 'client/**',
      // or this
      exclude: [
        '.git',
        '.nuxt',
        'app',
        'bootstrap',
        'config',
        'database',
        'node_modules',
        'public',
        'resources',
        'routes',
        'storage',
        'tests',
        'vendor'
      ]
    }
  }
},
```

but the error is as same as it before: the `Vite` still watch all the folders under root dir

[image]

---

How can I config the `Vite` so the folders can be watched correctly?

Comment: Have you tried `server.watch`?